# Can the google protobuf library be used to serialize an unknown binary protobuf into a ruby object, then back again?

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers

I understand that the binary protobuf format has no context (without the proto def), but all the same, I have a requirement to be able to deserialize it into a ruby object that can be enumerated and changed, and then reserialize the object back into binary protobuf format.

The google protobuf docs for ruby are really light in comparison to the other supported languages, so it isn't clear if this is possible, or how to go about it.

If the google protobuf library isn't the best choice, is there a better one (that supports all the protobuf versions)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to deaerialize a protocol buffer without knowing what its fields are? You can't, not meaningfully. They're not self-describing. Maybe instead describe the problem you're trying to solve this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I found that I couldn't get what I wanted from the Google library. However, the wire protocol is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), and there are only six variable types used.

In the end I created a simple class that can deserialize all the TLVs, and for the LEN type, recognise (and permute strings), recurse on embedded messages, and skip everything else.

Answer (score 2):

No, the [protocol buffer wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) is not self-describing. Without a schema file there's only a limited amount of information which can be extracted.

There is [protoscope](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protoscope), a sort of decompiler. That will show you how much information you can get from the wire format, though it is not exact.

Comment: The use case is a protocol fuzzer for QA. And like I said, I know the context is missing without the proto defs. But actually, all the information that I need is in the binary: it's a sequence of variable length values (not all that different from other formats, such as ASN1 etc). I simply need to be able to get at the values, change some of them, and reserialize. If I can use the google library (or an alternative) to do the heavy lifting of the de/re-serialization, then all good. If not, then I'll build my own.

Comment: @Buffoonism If it's for fuzzing, perhaps you could generate random protobuf files and round trip from them? What are you fuzzing?

Comment: No, sending random protobufs is likely to be a bit of a waste of time, as they are unlikely to match the expected schema at the far end, and be dropped at the deserialisation stage, before the contents are reused in the app. I'm not looking to QA the serializer, but the app that receives the data. This is something much more targeted: fuzzing a string, based on context. If it contains a JSON structure, it can be enumerated itself. If it contains a URI, alternatives can be tried. But to do so first requires deserializing the binary, and then reserializing it keeping the structure intact.

Comment: @Buffoonism You have a schema?

Comment: No, all I have is what is on the wire, the binary protocol. I understand that without the proto def, I can't add specific context to the fields, but that isn't actually important: all I need to do is deserialize the binary into a set of fields, change some of them, then reserialize it back into the same binary structure. To get back to the original question though: is this something the google protobuf library can do for me (the heavy lifting of encoding/decoding the binary protocol etc) or is this something another library can do easily, or do I just need to get on and write my own. ;)

Comment: @Buffoonism Like the answer says, you can't deserialize without the schema. protoscope can make a guess at deserializing, but if you want to modify and re-serialize I think you're on you're own. The wire protocol isn't very complicated. I would look for a different way to accomplish your task, perhaps a different level of the stack.

Comment: Actually, you can deserialize just fine. and make some reasonable guesses about whether the contents of a LEN is a string, a substructure, or binary data. In fact, I ran up what I needed yesterday. ;)